# two sample t.test error in R

Tags: r

I want to compare two columns from two different datasets with each other. However:

```
t.test(dataframe$column, dataframe2$column, alternative="greater").
```

Gives me the following error:

> Error in if (stderr < 10 * .Machine$double.eps * abs(mx)) stop("data are essentially constant") : 
>     missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

The error has to do with the second dataframe, because with the first dataframe I am able to conduct a one-sample *t*-test without getting any error.

Background info:
The data in the columns represents the ratio of "Travel distance to trip duration" , and the two dataframes are two different cities, as I would like to see if there are any significant differences in this ratio in the two different cities.

The ratios are mostly small numbers with many decimals.

Edit:

> str(dataframe2$column)
>    atomic [1:67553] 0.0397 0.054 0.2141 0.2362 0.432 ...
>    - attr(*, "units")= chr "mins"

Can somebody help me with the error and tell me where it comes from?

Comment: sample data would help.  What do you get for `str(dataframe2$column)`?

Comment: @EmmaOlivia, have you tried putting both columns together in one dataframe and running the test? Basically the following: `newdf <- data.frame(column1 = dataframe$column, column2 = dataframe2$column)` and then `t.test(column1, column2, alternative="greater", data=newdf)`

Comment: Also, I just debugged the `t.test()` function to find where that error actually occurs, and I found that this error is following by `stop("data are essentially constant")`. To me, this means that the standard errors that the function needs in order to yield a result are almost `zero`. That said, I am going to guess that the data in the columns are either very close to zero or are constant; which means that standard errors will be essentially zeros.